# Convert Hex to String: special characters not converted properly

Tags: vb.net, encoding, hex

I have to convert the following hex encoded string:

> 56 6f 6e 68 c3 b6 67 65 6e

The result should be: Vonhöger
However, the result I get is: VonhÃ¶ger

What is wrong with my code?

```
For x = 0 To hexString.Length - 1 Step 2
    Dim k As String = hexString.Substring(x, 2)
    If (k <> "X'") Then
       com &= Chr(Val("&h" & k))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The problem is that you need to use Unicode - Chr returns the ASCII char and there isn't one for ö - the code is c3 b6 which is a two byte code.

Comment: In that case, how can I check for a two byte character?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 explains but basically if the first character has a value over 7fH then it is a 2 or more byte character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting each byte to a unicode character, but the data is UTF-8 encoded, so some bytes in combination forms a character. The bytes `c3 b6` is the code for the [`ö` character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f6/index.htm).

Convert the data into bytes, then decode it as UTF-8:

```
Dim hexString = "566f6e68c3b667656e"

Dim bytes() As Byte
ReDim bytes(hexString.Length \ 2 - 1)

For i As Integer = 0 To bytes.Length - 1
  bytes(i) = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16)
Next

Dim com As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your example however doesn't seem to work? The ReDim gives only one byte correct?

Comment: @MartinH: I tested the code before posting. The `ReDim` makes the array half the length of the string.

Comment: Your correct. I had to adjust your code to get it working in my program. And I adjusted it wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other suggestions:

```
<Extension>
Public Function FromHexToUnicodeString(target As String) As String
    Dim bytes((target.Length \ 2) - 1) As Byte

    For b = 0 To bytes.Length - 1
        bytes(b) = Convert.ToByte(target.Substring(b * 2, 2), 16)
    Next

    Return Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
    MessageBox.Show("566f6e68c3b667656e".FromHexToUnicodeString)
```